# how to decode JSON API response

Tags: java, post, response, decode

I am trying to retrieve the response of api 
I am using the following code to retrieve the response

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class POST {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36";
    private String url;
    private String urlParameters;
    private String Cookie;
    StringBuffer response;

    public POST(String url ,String urlParameters,String Cookie){
        this.url = url;
        this.urlParameters = urlParameters;
        this.Cookie = Cookie;
    }

    public String sendPost() throws Exception {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "_abck="+Cookie);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        if(responseCode == 200){
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"UTF8"));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

But I am getting the response in decoded form as ���n� �߅\f]as��DՊ�I��/�m�(��*Ʃ���Kc���

How to decode the api response?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTcbs.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the response were JSON, I would expect to see "text".  Clearly you're getting a response ... but it looks like it might be binary data (instead of JSON text).  SUGGESTION: Call your API using "Chrome Developer Tools > Network tab" or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to inspect your response data.

Comment: yes response  is json object

Comment: I think the problem is with the charset you specified. You missed the hyphen in UTF8. It should be `UTF-8`. There are chances this may fix it.

Comment: @Kones Jone - the output you're showing sure doesn't look like JSON!  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Verify the actual HTTP response message with Chrome/Developer Tools or Fiddler, 2) Check  Navjot Waraich's excellent suggestion about mis-spelling "UTF-8".  PS: Java 1.7 introduced `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()`.

Comment: It's most likely due to gzip compression that's why you're seeing jargon.